# Title length error

Tags: 7, nodes

We just started receiving the following error when attempting to add a new content item: "Title cannot be longer than 70 characters but is currently 79 characters long." This happens regardless of the actual title length and the numbers in the error message are always the same, ie. the title "Test Title" returns that same error. This just started happening recently and the only change to the site that I can think of is a recent update from Drupal 7.97 to Drupal 7.98. FWIW, this problem seems to only occur when trying to add this content type (Resource). We're able to add other content types without any problem. Any ideas why this suddenly started happening?

[image]

UPDATE:
I installed our 7.97 backup on a test server. It does not exhibit the problem. Here's a screenshot of the available updates. At the time of the 7.98 update I also updated all of the other items except for the Webform Ajax module. Is there anything else here that possibly could be involved?
[image: available updates]

Comment: Drupal 7.98 released in June so this probably is not a widespread problem with Drupal Core. So unfortunately to get a factual answer contributors on this site will have to interview you for more information—information that only you have. But this website isn't optimized for interviews so you must provide more info.

Comment: Is there anything specific that you believe would be helpful to add?

Comment: Clean installs of Drupal 7 do not suffer from this problem so it's on you to explain in what way this site differs from that.

Comment: Try disabling various modules, starting with custom modules, to see if the problem goes away. Make sure to take a backup first so you can reinstall it after you figure out where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I'll start doing that. But where is the function that evaluates the length of the title during editing? And also, I just don't understand why it only is causing an error on this one specific content type.

Comment: Just for debugging purpose , you can check schema/db level what is the length of title field for specific content type & any specific error maintain on status report , It can be possibility db updates not executed property after Drupal core updates, any specific custom code added in custom module/theme , you can try search by "machine_name_content_type" in project directory

Comment: I looked at the table 'node' and the field 'title' and it is set for 255 char. There isn't any specific title field for that specific content item. All of the content items apparently use the default node/title field. Also, we don't have any custom modules in this site. I'm going to install the 7.97 backup on a test server and experiment from there.

Comment: There must be a contrib or custom module or something causing this. I'd start by tracing the "the title cannot be longer than" and going from there.

Comment: I'm still working on troubleshooting this. Just to do a recap: I installed the backup from before the problem started onto a test server. I then did the Drupal 7.97 to 7.98 update and all was still good. I then started updating the modules in the screenshot above one at a time. When I got to the Metatag module the problem appeared. Any ideas why the Metatag module would cause this type of error?